# Randomly choose a Animation Flip in Android

Tags: android, flip, viewanimator

Not sure how to ask this, I have been trying to work out the best method to implement a random card generator. Similar to a Flash Card or Tarot card. I have found lots of examples that explain the flipping of a card, which is great but I need it to:

1. Randomly pick the card
2. Display the description of that card either by flipping and showing the back or going to a completely new view.

Below is the code that I have using Fragments and I have worked out the Random part using the `Random()`. What I'm struggling with is once the button is pressed it goes to the correct card and further more the correct description for that card.

I originally had this in the onCreate method which is fine, but I put it into a button so I could control it a bit more but I do understand that in order to invoke the flip the user will touch the screen. Are there any tutorials or suggests one can provided to help me work this out? I got it working in iOS in a day surely this has been done before.

```
public void ButtonOnClick(View v) {
    final ViewAnimator viewAnimator1 = (ViewAnimator)this.findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
    final ViewAnimator viewAnimator2 = (ViewAnimator)this.findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper2);
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int randomListIndex = rnd.nextInt(4);
    switch (randomListIndex) {
        //Card1
        case 1:
            //Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Flip3DViewTransitionActivity.class);
            //startActivity(intent);
            AnimationFactory.flipTransition(viewAnimator1, AnimationFactory.FlipDirection.RIGHT_LEFT);
        break;
        //Card2
        case 2:
             AnimationFactory.flipTransition(viewAnimator1, AnimationFactory.FlipDirection.RIGHT_LEFT);
        break;
        //Card3
        case 3:
            AnimationFactory.flipTransition(viewAnimator2, AnimationFactory.FlipDirection.RIGHT_LEFT);
        break;
        //Card4
        case 4:
            AnimationFactory.flipTransition(viewAnimator2, AnimationFactory.FlipDirection.RIGHT_LEFT);
        break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I worked it out. I took a different approach. As you can see above I should have done a few things different. I ended up ditching the flip effect and worked with a fade in effect. I know it didn't answer the question entirely. However I was able to achieve what I set out to do. Hope this helps someone in the future.

```
ImageView image;
    public void ButtonOnClick(View v) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int randomListIndex = rnd.nextInt(2);
        Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Tarot.this, R.anim.fadein);
        switch (randomListIndex) {
            case 0:

                //get the image your going to muck with
                image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cardImageView);
                //set the image with what it should be
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.storm);
                //apply the transition effect so it looks correct
                image.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
            break;
            case 1:
                image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cardImageView);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.scribe);
                image.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);

            break;
            default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

Regards,
Jeremy